# after ajax call jquery function's not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

For example :

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".main_category", function(){  
    var cat_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.get("/?category_filter", { cat_id: cat_id }, function(data) {
        $(".owl-wrapper").html(data);
    });
});

$('#conn').isotope({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.owl-item',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});
```

Comment: What exactly 'does not work' after the AJAX call?

Comment: There are any message in browser´s console? was you that implement the server side method? what language are you using?

Comment: All functions in my script for example:
  $('#conn').isotope({
    itemSelector : '.owl-item',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows'

  });
 $('a:first').fancyzoom({Speed:400,showoverlay:false});
 $('a:last').fancyzoom({Speed:400,showoverlay:false});
 $('#nooverlay').fancyzoom({Speed:400,showoverlay:false});
 $('.fancyzoom').fancyzoom();

Comment: @beqa -- Are these functions by chance targetting elements that are children of `.owl-wrapper`?

Comment: I using php and when returns data all jquery functions not working.

Comment: I don't understand your question tymeJV ?

Comment: @bega Can you pass value of "data"?

Comment: Yes i can pass value of "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".main_category", function(){  
    var cat_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.get("/?category_filter", { cat_id: cat_id }, function(data) {
        $(".owl-wrapper").html(data);
        $("#conn").isotope("reloadItems").isotope();
    });
});
```

It will make isotope refresh/rebuild itself after you change the items.